# Що означає слово "канархистр"

Tags: значення-слів

Наткнувся на таке речення:

> ...в монастирі Святомихайловськом при ігумені Іоаникії Сенютовичу і при
>   наміснику Варсонуфії і уставнику Гедеоні, за **канархистру** лівого
>   кліроса, ...

Цікавить значення слова "канархистр", бо в СУМі його немає. Також знайшов це слово [тут](http://philology.lnu.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC.pdf), і судячи із завдання (ст.63) - це архаїзм та назва якоїсь професії.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [ЗВЕДЕНОМУ СЛОВНИКУ ЗАСТАРІЛИХ ТА МАЛОВЖИВАНИХ СЛІВ](http://litopys.org.ua/rizne/zvslovnyk.htm) натрапляємо на таке визначення:

> **Канархистр — церковний співак**